# How to Integrate Pycharm and git with azure machile learning service (workspace)

Tags: python, azure, pycharm, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to create a machine learning pipeline using python with PyCharm and run everything in azure machine learning service workspace. Then I want to integrate my pycharm script in a way when I edit and save my script, it runs a new experiment in Azure ML workspace.

I have check all the tutorials on using Azure ML service using python sdk, however, every time it is via notebooks but not with pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Machine Learning service can be used from any editor that supports Python 3.5 - 3.7: PyCharm, VSCode or just plain python.exe. We've used Notebooks because it makes it easy to package and present the examples, however you should be able to copy-paste the Python code and run in any editor.